# Maven parent/child project relationship

Tags: maven, dependencies, parent, pom.xml

I'm fairly new to Maven, and although I've been having some success there has always been one aspect that has confused me.  When I try to research the topic I seem to go around in circles, which makes me think I'm missing something fundamental.

This is what confuses me:

- A child project declares its parent in the POM. If I have a general purpose utility project that is used by several other projects then I don't understand how the parent/child relationship will work.

Let's say I have two web applications: Product-1 and Product-2.

- Product-1 depends on a security project, and that security project depends on a utility project.
- Product-2 depends on a utility project and a framework project.

In the Product-1 POM I'd like to be able to specify the versions of the security and utility projects. The tricky bit for me is that I'd like to override the security project and dictate the version of the utility project it should use.

I've seen solutions to this problem that would allow all the versions to be specified in the Product-1 POM, and they would be "inherited" by the child projects.  But I believe those solutions rely on each child project referencing its parent project.  I can't do that in the case of the utility project as it could be used by more than one parent.

Is there a way to specify child versions in the Product-1 POM, so they cascade down to all the children, without the child projects knowing what the parent is?

I've seen similar questions asked before, but haven't found an answer yet. That makes me think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental, or it's the wrong question to ask.

Any enlightenment would be gratefully received.  Thanks.

EDIT:
Link to the dependency management handling referred to earlier.  This provides some example pom files.

- http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management

Comment: _Is there a way to specify child versions in the Product-1 POM, so they cascade down to all the children, without the child projects knowing what the parent is?_ I don't understand this clearly, would you mind posting tiny `pom.xml` as an example to explain your problem

Comment: Hi Jigar.  Thanks for the quick response.  I've edited my question to include a link to the dependency management documentation. That provides an example pom file.  See where it says: "The dependency management section is a mechanism for centralizing dependency information"

Comment: I don't see pom.xml as an reference example